# Rendering a mesh with VTK api

Tags: mesh, vtk, finite-element-analysis

I'm making a simpler viewer to read and visualize a mesh.

VTK is new to me and I'm first trying to figure out the best/most efficient way to set up the mesh data for the viewer. I see there are many examples of VTK with c++, but a lot of them are to convert to vtk format or rendering primitives.

I'm not interested in converting to vtk format, I just what to set up my mesh data to a *vtk unstructured grid* or *vtk poly data set* and render it.

I've done a little test. The code bellow correctly renders, but is this the most efficient way to set up the dataset? If I set `N_SQUARES` to 1 000 000, it works, but the triangle loop seems very slow.

```
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();


    //TEST MESH
    int N_SQUARES = 100;

    //This creates node coordinates for N_SQUARES amount of squares. (Nodal data would be read from a file later on)
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> nodes = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();   

    for (int i = 0; i < N_SQUARES; i++){
        nodes->InsertNextPoint(0.0, 0.0, 0.0 + 0.2f*float(i));
        nodes->InsertNextPoint(1.0, 0.0, 0.0 + 0.2f*float(i));
        nodes->InsertNextPoint(1.0, 1.0, 0.0 + 0.2f*float(i));
        nodes->InsertNextPoint(0.0, 1.0, 0.2 + 0.2f*float(i));
    }

    //Here two triangles are created for each square. (these indices would later on be read from FEM element data)
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> triangles = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();

    for (int j = 0; j < N_SQUARES; j++){
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangle> triangle1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangle>::New();
        triangle1->GetPointIds()->SetId(0, 0 + j);
        triangle1->GetPointIds()->SetId(1, 1 + j);
        triangle1->GetPointIds()->SetId(2, 2 + j);

        vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangle> triangle2 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangle>::New();
        triangle2->GetPointIds()->SetId(0, 2 + j);
        triangle2->GetPointIds()->SetId(1, 3 + j);
        triangle2->GetPointIds()->SetId(2, 0 + j);


        triangles->InsertNextCell(triangle1);
        triangles->InsertNextCell(triangle2);
    }

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> meshData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
    meshData->SetPoints(nodes);
    meshData->SetPolys(triangles);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> meshMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    meshMapper->SetInputData(meshData);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> meshActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    meshActor->SetMapper(meshMapper);

    renderer->AddActor(meshActor);


    ui.qvtkWidget->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(renderer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your example could be slow for any of several reasons

- You are constructing and destroying 2 vtkTriangle instances inside your `j`-loop. This is expensive and probably the largest cause of slowness.
- Since you build polydata, it would be best to avoid using vtkTriangle at all. Instead, do something like

  ```
  for (int j = 0; j < N_SQUARES; ++j)
  {
    vtkIdType triangle1[3] = {j, j+1, j+2};
    vtkIdType triangle2[3] = {j+2, j+3, j};
    triangles->InsertNextCell(3, triangle1);
    triangles->InsertNextCell(3, triangle2);
    // ... or better yet, create a single quad:
    vtkIdType quad[4] = {j, j+1, j+2, j+3};
    triangles->InsertNextCell(4, quad);
  }
  ```
- You don't tell VTK how big the arrays (point coordinates or connectivity) are going to be ahead of time. This means VTK must reallocate and copy the arrays as you increase their size. Try adding `nodes->GetData()->Allocate(4 * N_SQUARES);` before your first loop (over `i`). Similarly, you can tell the vtkCellArray to allocate the right amount of memory ahead of time (a little tricky; it is an array of integers formatted like so: nptsPerPoly0 ptId0Poly0 ptId1Poly0 ... ptIdNPoly0 nPtsPerPoly1 ...). For triangles, you would call `triangles->Allocate((1 + 3) * 2 * N_SQUARES);`. For quads as in the previous example, it would be `triangles->Allocate((1 + 4) * N_SQUARES);`.
- Your example doesn't re-use points that are shared by multiple squares. That makes both `nodes` and `triangles` consume much more memory than necessary.
- For medium-sized meshes (fit in memory on a single computer), you can use threading to prepare the `nodes` and `triangles` arrays. For large meshes, VTK is built to work across multiple computers where each one holds only part of the mesh (distributed-memory parallelism).
- If you already have the mesh in memory, recent versions of VTK allow you to write special classes that expose the mesh to VTK without requiring any copies, but that's beyond the scope of this question. However, it would halve the amount of memory a given mesh consumes so it could be important depending on the mesh and your computer's memory.
- Depending on how big you make `N_SQUARES`, you could be causing your computer to use a swap file or partition. In that case you should reduce the size of your mesh or use distributed-memory parallelism.

Comment: Thank you! This is the kind of answer I needed. Will modify my code and test it out. I have some experience with OpenGL and the use of buffer and so on for rendering. I believe "under the hood" VTK uses this. Is there any overview of how VTK invokes the different OpenGL methods?

Comment: @remi000 All of VTK's OpenGL calls are confined to classes in either the  `VTK/Rendering/OpenGL` or `VTK/Rendering/OpenGL2` directories (depending on whether you use the old, or new OpenGL backend. Inside the director, the calls to OpenGL are split across many classes. For instance, `vtkOpenGLPolyDataMapper.cxx` populates `vtkOpenGLVertexBufferObject` instances with data; calls that bind/upload the buffer objects are in `vtkOpenGLBufferObject` (the superclass of `vtkOpenGLVertexBufferObject`).